# COMException was unhandled when trying to save Excel workbook

Tags: c#, .net, windows, excel

I'm trying to create and save an Excel workbook to my desktop and so far have the following C# code:

```
   using System
   using System.Net
   using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

   //LAUNCH AND TEMPLATE EXCEL
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
   Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
   Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1]
   ws.Cells[1, 1] = "Report Date";
   ws.Cells[1, 2] = "Catagories";
   ws.Cells[1, 3] = "Page Name";
   ws.Cells[1, 4] = "Last Revision Date";
   ws.Cells[1, 5] = "Beginning Total";
   ws.Cells[1, 6] = "Ending Total";
   ws.Cells[1, 7] = "Monthly Total";
   ws.Cells[1, 8] = "YTD";
   //LAUNCH AND TEMPLATE EXCEL

   wb.SaveCopyAs("C:/Users/pta72645/Desktop/TestFile5_2.xlsx"); //save Excel, **ERROR OCCURS HERE**
```

The error that occurs on the very last line where I try to save the workbook instance. Visual Studio says: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in wikiScrapeData.exe". I have looked on MSDN and other sources and have not been able to solve the issue.

How do I properly save this Excel workbook?

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/ziagrosvenor/Wiki-Scrape in your project?

Comment: @Hackerman No, just a coincidence in naming.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try the `SaveAs()` method?

Comment: @Frecklefoot Yep, get the exact same error.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of at the moment is that it doesn't like the location you're saving it to. Try something simpler, like `@"C:\Temp\TestFile.xlsx"`. If that works, it gives you a hint at the solution.

Comment: The path separator on Windows is a backslash. Some file I/O API calls will convert forward slashes, but this is not true for all. You are better off using the correct path separator.

Comment: @IInspectable: you are correct, but the .NET framework accepts either, so that's not the source of his problem here.

Comment: @Frecklefoot: The `Workbook` is a COM object. Even if .NET accepts both characters as a path separator (which I doubt, but I'm too lazy to check the reference source), it is irrelevant. .NET does not translate path arguments passed to a native COM object.

Comment: @IInspectable, okay, then, xDr_Johnx, have you tried replacing the forward slashes with backslashes?